# MacBook Air (bought in August 2014)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, software-update

With the recent Yosemite software update (I updated on 23rd February 2015) the cool 'bubble' sound that the volume keys made when pressed is now gone and replaced with a different sound. How do I get the old one back?

Comment: @IconDaemon Whilst that's related, that's not a duplicate—it still requires the original file to replace the new file with.

Answer (score 0):

While it is always difficult to describe the sound (I can only guess which one you mean), I am offering you to find it first.

```
/System/Library/Sounds/
```

Once found:

Copy the file to desktop and rename it in to Volume.aiff

Now go here `/System/Library/LoginPlugins/BezelServices.loginPlugin/Contents/Resources/` find and rename the Volume.aiff in to oldvolume.aiff

Last step, move the file from desktop in to this folder.